# Background Repeat not working in IE

Tags: html, css

IE is really playing up (as usual), I've got a div with an image in the bottom right hand corner set to 'no-repeat', but IE is rendering with repeated images...

Here's a link if anyone would be kind enough to check it out - it's half way down the right hand side column entitled 'advertise':

http://inside-guides.co.uk/brentwood/pages/index.html

Here's the CSS (can also check on the developer's tools)

```
.right-nav .bg.advertise-home {background:url(/images/Structure/sign.png) right 100% no-repeat;}
```

Any ideas??  Hate ie!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to be caused by the **border-radius.htc** behaviour you use.

If it is this one: http://code.google.com/p/curved-corner/ then you should look at the issues as it seems to be a known issue with some patches near the end of the discussion..

http://code.google.com/p/curved-corner/issues/detail?id=1

Answer (score 1):

It might be caused by your shorthand:

```
background:url(/images/Structure/sign.png) right 100% no-repeat;
```

should be:

```
background:url(/images/Structure/sign.png) no-repeat right 100%;
```

Comment: Perhaps I'm missing an IE-ism, but why put 100% instead of just 'bottom'? Otherwise this answer is the one I was going to give.

Comment: @A. R. Younce I just copied the original css and `100%` is valid so I didn´t bother changing it.

Answer (score 0):

I only got XP installed on my VMware but I can tell you in XP the site is totally screwed. But I'm not sure if IE likes the 100%.

You could also add an important expression to make sure the CSS for this class is not being superseded ie.

```
.right-nav .bg.advertise-home {background:url(/images/Structure/sign.png) right 100% no-repeat !important;}
```